# How to change 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, axios

Developing a small app using Firebase, Axios, VueJS. When I test on Firefox, a PUT request works as expected. When testing on latest version of Chrome, however, I get the following message:

> Failed to load https://vuejs-stock-trader-XXXXX.firebaseio.com/data.json: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://localhost:8080' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

My local server is indeed sending an http rather than an https request, but I'm a bit stumped as to why this would work in FF and not Chrome. Is there any way to find/modify the ACAO header? Or, any suggestions for why this might work in one browser and not another?

Comment: Any reason why you're accessing Realtime Database with the REST API instead of the provided client SDKs (which handle all this for you)?

Comment: Yes. I'm learning VueJS and Axios and just using Firebase as a data server.

Comment: Well, if you use the Firebase client SDK, your work will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has some extra web security measures, if you open chrome with the option
`--disable-web-security` it should work fine.

To solve this for Chrome with security enabled you will need to modify your server-side response headers and add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or replace the * with the url you will be accessing it from.